# Spring RESTful webservice Hibernate/JPA Crudrepository - Get User by Movie title

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am pretty new to Spring Boot development and i need some help with a certain case.

I am creating a RESTful webservices with the JPA/Hibernate Spring and the CRUDrepository.(Json format)

So i have two tables like so:

user:

```
    +----+-------------+---------+
    | id |  username   | age     | 
    +----+-------------+---------+
    |  1 |  James      | 21      |
    |  2 |  Bond       | 41      |
    |  3 |  David      | 17      |
    |  4 |  Alfred     | 33      |
    +----+-------------+---------+
```

movie:

```
    +----+----------+-----------+
    | id| movie     | userId
    +----+----------+-----------+
    |  1 |  movie1  | 3
    |  2 |  movie2  | 3
    |  3 |  movie3  | 1
    |  4 |  movie4  | 4
    |  5 |  movie5  | 4
    |  7 |  movie6  | 2
    |  8 |  movie7  | 2
    |  9 |  movie1  | 1
    +----+----------+-----------+
```

Movie Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String title;

@Column
private int userId;

    protected Movie() {
        super();
    }

//constructors 
// getter setter

}
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String username;

@Column
private int age;


    protected User() {
        super();
    }

//constructors 
// getter setter

}
```

Movie Repository:

```
public interface MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie, Integer> {

    List<Movie> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

User Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="demo")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @GetMapping(path="/movie")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Movie> getAllMovies() {
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/user")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUser() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I am able to get all Users and all Movies as a json obejct result.

Now comes my question: how do i get a json object that has every user for a singel movie?I want to use a RequestParam aswell. Maybe something like so:

```
@GetMapping(path="/userbymovietitle")
    public @ResponseBody String getUserByMovies(@RequestParam("title") string title) {
         ....
    }
```

and the url will be something like this: localhost:8080/demo/userbymovietitle?title=movie1

then the response should look like this:

```
[
  { 
    id: 3
    username: David
    age: 17
  }
  { 
    id: 1
    username: James
    age: 21
  }
]
```

Comment: Please delete all the getter and setter methods.. We don't need  to see them

Comment: Too broad. You need to firstly to get a  grasp of the basics: fix the JPA mappings so the relationship from User <> Movie is modelled correctly. Once that is in place learn how to query and then look at the REST part.

Answer (score 1):

It depend you can use a `@RequestParam` or you can also use the 
 `@PathVariable`.

Using the first the url will be: `localhost:8080/demo/userbymovietitle?title=movie1` while with the second: `localhost:8080/demo/userbymovietitle/movie1`

and using the path variable the controller becomes

```
@GetMapping(path="/userbymovietitle/{title}")
    public @ResponseBody String getUserByMovies(@@PathVariable("title") string title) {
```

Anyway the problem is your `userId`....

You have to create a **relation** between these 2 tables.. So for example, if a user can have more than one movie and also a movie can be seen by many users, there is a many to many relation.
So inside your movie entity you must substitute the column `userId` with:

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Or in this case (because it is many to many relation) you could put the realtion inside the user.
So inside the user entity add:

```
@ManyToMany
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
```

I just done a quick search on web, but read this http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56738/one-to-one-one-to-many-table-relationships-in-sql-server/ or something similar that explains the relations between classes..

Anyway when you modify in that way, you can extract the users with a particular title..
T

Answer (score 0):

You should use JPA's entity relationship feature.

It's tempting to call this a ManyToMany relationship — a User appears in many Movies, and a Movie features many Users — but ManyToMany can only be implemented with a separate mapping table.

You don't have such a mapping table — instead, each Movie owns a mapping to exactly one User. Therefore I think you're describing a [OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) entity relationship.

I think it would look a bit like this (you'll probably need to add boring stuff like getters, setters, public no-arg constructor):

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Movie> movies;
}

@Entity
public class Movie {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;
}
```

Yes, we've removed `private int userId`. We now prefer `getUser().getId()`.

[Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)'s query derivation provides some methods to lookup an entity via a related entity. Here's two ways:

```java
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Integer> {
    List<Movie> findByUserId(long id);
    List<Movie> findByUser(User user);
}
```

You may also be able to find by Example:

```java
final User example = new User();
example.setId(1);
movieRepository.findAll(Example.of(example));
```

Endpoint would probably look a bit like this:

```java
@RequestMapping("/{userId}")
public List<User> findByUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
    return movieRepository.findByUser(userId);
}
```

Note: I've written all this blind, so it may not work verbatim. But it should be pretty close.